# Why ternary condition not working perfectly for string concatenation

Tags: python, python-3.x, ternary-operator, string-concatenation

I saw a peculiar behavior in python when using ternary operator in string concatenation -

```
>>> foo = "foo"
>>> foo.upper()
'FOO'
>>> bar = 2
>>> "" if bar is 0 else str(bar)
'2'
>>> foo.upper() + "_" + "" if bar is 0 else str(bar)
'2'
```

With the above code I was expecting it should output as `FOO_2` but only showing `2`. Though I can achieve the output with the below code. Can anyone explain why it is not working with `+` ?

```
>>> "{}_{}".format(foo.upper(), "" if bar is 0 else str(bar))
'FOO_2'
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: Aside: it's not relevant to your issue, but don't use `is` where you mean `==` -- see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) plays a crucial role here. The expression is evaluated as:

```
(foo.upper() + "_" + "") if bar is 0 else str(bar)
```

This is because conditional expressions precede addition and subtraction.

Use parenthesis to enforce your desired evaluation order:

```
foo.upper() + "_" + ("" if bar is 0 else str(bar))
```

Or, what is probably even better is to decrease complexity by [extracting a variable](https://refactoring.com/catalog/extractVariable.html) to avoid any possible confusion:

```
postfix = "" if bar is 0 else str(bar)
print(foo.upper() + "_" + postfix)
```